How do you master modelling in Blender?
I know this is a big question, but what I'm trying to find out is how do you reach this point where you can model anything.
there are lots of objects in life and everyone approaches modeling them in different ways and techniques, this makes things even harder because I can't find a specific method to model objects and apply it always.
so what should I do, I'm already struggling in modeling and didn't start texturing, geometry nodes...etc.

Specifically by not asking questions like that here! This Q&A site is here to help with modelling problems in Blender, not for general advice on learning to use it. Read the tour. Then try asking somewhere like https://blenderartists.org.

there's no real method, each object is different and will inspire a different strategy, depending on if the object is symmetrical, cylindrical, organic, etc, the best way is to follow a lot of tutorials and you'll get a better idea on how to do an object or another

Hi, Someo one, I hope you don't mind my edit of the title, but your question really seems to be specifically about modelling, not Blender in general(which would be closed even faster as opinion based and off-topic).

I am not a master of Blender by any means but...
PRACTICE, and practice with intention. Follow tutorials, complete courses, join a modelling community and ask specific questions that fix your specific problems. When you encounter issues, DO NOT give up until you figure out how to fix it.
Start small (i.e., low poly), and stay consistent. You reach the point where you can model anything after you model a bit of everything.
Finally, I will say that you have to have some passion for it. Do you enjoy learning Blender? Try to embrace issues you encounter as challenges that will level-up your skills as an artist.
Good luck!

It's difficult to answer how you reach this level, and the way will be different for different people, but it might be helpful to consider what it is to be able to model any forms and how it is done and what separate smaller skills you need.
You definitely need a few things in order to be able to model anything:

The knowledge of all available functionality of the software. You need to know what each function does precisely or at least attempt to know as much as possible. Poly modelling in Blender involves all the functions in the menus of the 3D Viewport header in Edit mode(Select, Add, Mesh, Vertex, Edge, Face, UV), and Object mode(Select, Add, Object) so you should know what each function does well(I am not suggesting to actually use the menus - you should probably use hotkeys while modelling in Blender, most of us do). You can optionally use tools in the Toolbar, so you would need to know how to use them if you choose that. You should know what the modifiers do as well. That includes one tricky one - Geometry Nodes. It's up to you how deep you go with that one. Understanding other functionality like how to transform objects or elements is also crucial. You should know how Transform Orientations, Transform Pivot Point, snapping and proportional editing works. There are also benefits in understanding other functionality like what you can do with curve objects and so on. There is sculpting as well and you might need to use simulations for certain things(like for example you would use cloth simulation for modelling clothes, but also some other objects like for example soft furniture so simulations are also sometimes part of modelling). That's basically the knowledge of everything the software can do including many things I fail to mentions here.

The other big part is the ability to see the forms(observation is one very important skill that you need to train a lot) that make up objects and choose workflows(series of actions) that will let you atchieve them. That is something you cannot read in the manual or learn watching a single tutorial. You need to know a lot of ways to model a lot of forms - that's sort of understanding and intuition about how all the different functions work together, how you can combine them and what results you can expect when you combine different techniques. This comes with a lot of practice and you need lots of time for this. You find certain ways to model certain things just by trying while practicing or by watching many tutorials and learn them(sometimes subconsciously). So it's not enough just to learn the functions and you absolutely need to practice a lot as well in order to learn many techniques and how to combine them.


